# Model becomes null when any of the parameters is null

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-core, angular5

In my Angular 5 application, I would like to save an "event" object with the following method :

```
save(newEvent: NewEvent): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
    const requestUrl = 'api/event';
    return this.http.post<any>(requestUrl, newEvent, httpOptions);
  }
```

The NewEvent model is :

```
export class NewEvent {
  id: number;
  title: string;...

  constructor() {
    this.id = null;
    this.title = '';...
  }
}
```

And after I call this with a method in a controller with .NET Core :

```
[HttpPost("api/event")]
public IDictionary<string, Object> SaveEvent([FromBody] EventViewModel model){...}
```

The EventViewModel POCO is :

```
{
    public class EventViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }...
    }
}
```

When my object `EventViewModel` has no attributes with a "null" value it works with no problems, but when I have "null" attributes it doesn't work (the `EventViewModel` became "null") and I want to have sometimes "null" attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C# model has a non-nullable `int` for the Id column. If you want it to be nullable (as you set it to null in your javascript model) you should define it as `int?` or `Nullable<int>`.

See also: [Nullable Types.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/index)

Comment: 23 years I've been doing .NET and I only just came across this disgusting behaviour. It should use the default values or throw. Not become null and send everyone on a wild goose chase looking at network traffic.